# Protractor Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine, protractor

I started with basic protractor test to test the title of the page. I am using **angular 2.4.10** and **"protractor": "^5.1.2"** When I run the protractor, I get this error.

**Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application.**

this is my sample code

```
//protractor.config.js
exports.config={
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs:['index.spec.js'],
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',

},
useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
framework: 'jasmine',

};

//index.spec.js
describe('hello-protractor', function() {
   it('title', function() {

    browser.get('http://localhost:8100/#/');

    var title = element(by.cssContainingText('My Dashboard Title'));
    expect(title.getText()).toEqual('My Dashboard Title');
    expect(title.getAttribute("text")).toEqual('My Dashboard Title');
  });
});
```

I referred this link to fix https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular

I set this attribute to `allScriptsTimeout:30000` but it showed me `**Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL**`

Answer (score -1):

From the information you have given it seems like either the page you are testing doens't contain the angular element or the timeout needs to be increased.

Ok here is the solution you have increased the Protractor specific time out.

But you can override the jasmine time out too.

try including this in the config.js file.

```
jasmineNodeOpts: {
isVerbose: true,
showColors: true,
defaultTimeoutInterval: 400000
  },
```

Also i saw that you have mentioned the framework:jasmine.

Are you sure this is just jasmine or jasmine2?

If you are using jasmine2 version please change that to framework:'jasmine2'

Kinldy let me know if it works. 
And if it works please consider accepting my answer and up voting it.

Comment: Hey..It did not work. I changed the framework to:'jasmine2'. I have defined the title in app.component.ts and in app-routing.module.ts, I am loading another component forRoot. Which has http service call

Comment: may i have the snippet of your html?

Comment: also i am not sure you have installed the jasmine 2 version. Did you ?

Comment: I did not install jasmine2. I installed protractor.                               
 `import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { Link } from './frame/model';                              
    @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
    })
   export class AppComponent {

   title = 'My  Dashboard title';`

Comment: Jasmine is insatlled along with protractor by default

Comment: would it be possible to give me the HTML rendered while you are locating the element. And also install the jasmine 2 with this command

Comment: npm install -g jasmine@2